# Trouble with multer and saving mongodb model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, multer

I am using multer to upload a file to my backend. Here is the route:

```
// @route  POST api/users/resume
// @desc   Upload user resume
// @access Private
router.post("/resume", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let resumeBackupName = null;

    let resumeMatrix = {
      "application/vnd.ms-excel": "xls",
      "application/msword": "doc",
      "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document":
        "docx",
      "application/pdf": "pdf"
    };

    let user = await User.findById({ _id: req.user.id.toString() });

    if (
      user.resume &&
      user.resume.extension &&
      user.resume.extension.length > 0
    ) {
      resumeBackupName =
        req.user.id.toString() +
        "-backup-" +
        user.resume.extension.length.toString() +
        "." +
        user.resume.extension[user.resume.extension.length - 1];

      user.resume.backup.push(resumeBackupName);
    }

    let date = new Date();
    let resumeMimeType = null;
    let resumeExtension = null;

    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, "public");
      },
      filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(
          null,
          req.user.id.toString() +
            "-" +
            date.getTime() +
            "-" +
            file.originalname
        );
      }
    });

    const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single("file");

    upload(req, res, err => {
      resumeMimeType = req.file.mimetype;
      resumeExtension = resumeMatrix[resumeMimeType];

      user.resume.mimeType = resumeMimeType;
      user.resume.extension.push(resumeExtension);

      if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
        return res.status(500).json(err);
      } else if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json(err);
      }
    });

    await user.save();

    return res.json({ msg: "Success!" });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send("Server error");
  }
});
```

The problem is within the upload function. Console logging `user` after the  `user.resume.mimeType = resumeMimeType;` and `user.resume.extension.push(resumeExtension);` lines properly displays the values, but when `await user.save()` is hit, it doesn't save anything. Is it a scoping issue? I'm getting a warning `variables declared but never used` for `let resumeMimeType = null;` and `let resumeExtension = null;`, but they are used in the upload function. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `user.markModified('resume')` before save

Comment: I added `user.markModified('resume')` within the upload method, it didn't work. I also tried putting it just above the `await user.save()`, still no dice :(